# Ajax sending date data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my jquery script, it is returning error when I try to send the date value from my form, when I leave it in blank, it doesn't show me an error.

```
<div class="field-wrap">
    <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="30" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</input>
</div> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#entrarBt').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'registro_dpb.php',
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST               
            data: $("#miForm").serialize(), // will be in $_POST on PHP side

            success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
                // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
                alert("Response is: " + data);
            },
            error: function() {
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.serialize()` is mostly for http vars. If you are going to use $_POST, I would suggest using `serializeArray()`. What does the dump look like on $_POST from your PHP script?

Comment: I hesitate because of the mention *«is returning error when I try to send»* **AND** right after *«it doesn't show me any error»*...  Normally,  I would just say *«replace `.serialize(...)` by `.val()` for a test. ;)

Comment: I already tried that but the error is coming again, I the problem is not with the php file I think, because even if I use the value or not, the problem appears, I will update my post with php anyway!

Comment: Would you mind to chat? I may help on english or on phrasing a bit more efficiently. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129303/hey

Comment: You needed 20 rep point to chat... 1 upvote did the trick. Re-try.

Comment: whats the error in your ajax response? see your network response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was pretty subtile... Making it hard to find.
But the solution is really simple.

You use a `<button>` inside a `<form>` which is absolutely correct.

But you have to know that in HTML5, **if the type** of a `<button>` is not explicitly defined as "button", its default type is "submit".

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button).

**This was the issue...**
Since you want to submit using an ajax request, which allow to receive a response without reloading the page, you have to "prevent" this normal behavior of a `<button>`.

The submit made by the button was not sent to your PHP script, but to your HTML page (there was no other `action` defined in the `<form>` tag, so the default is "self".
So the page reloads... Making your ajax request to fail.

So there is two ways to fix this:

**1**: Define the button `type` as "button":

```
<button type="button" id="entrarBt" [+ other attributes]>Entrar</button>
```

or
**2**: Prevent this default behavior using [`prevent.default()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in you click handler.

```
$('#entrarBt').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    
  $.ajax({
      //...
```

I think the second one is more evident for another programmer who could review your code, but the first is ok too.

---

For the benefit of the other SO readers:
We *(me and Javier)* checked almost every other error possibilities [in chat][3].
I finally found the cause when, for a test, I commented out the whole ajax block and then noticed that the page was still submitting.

Fixing this completely resolved the issue.

This is a tricky thing to absolutely know!
**In short, a `<button>` within a HTML5 `<form>` is a submit by default!**